# Mat class of c++ in open cv

Tags: image-processing, opencv, c

I am a beginner in opencv and have started learning it using visual studio 2012 and opencv 2.4.7 . But i got stuck at very beginning .I want to know about Mat used in Opencv .It is a class and an image name is a variable of this class .i just know this .but still i am feeling like i didn't get it totally like what are its data members and member functions?

Answer (score 1):

`Mat` declares a variable of type Matrix which can have multiple dimensions. In VS

```
Mat image = imread('test.bmp'); //lets consider a 2d image for now
```

Now put a `.` in front of `image` and the member functions will be exposed.